# How to open existing instances of apps from windows 10 Start Menu?

Tags: windows, windows-10, search

Coming from Mac, I'm used to opening apps with search. I'm trying to do the same with Windows 10 (Press Windows key, type in "Program Name", press enter), but this always opens a new instance of an app even if an existing one already exists. What can I do to make Windows 10 open existing apps instead, and only open a new instance if there are no instances already open?

Comment: Trying to launch an app again often starts a new occurrence and that is normal Windows behavior. If the app is open (like Excel with a file or a browser window, then then app is in the Taskbar near the left. Click on that and the same app opens The latter is always true. Whether an app opens new occurrence when you launch it again depends on the app.

Comment: Switching to an existing instance is the job of the started program on Windows. Running apps should be selected using the icons in the task bar.

Comment: Although, "mouse overuse" it's solution for all in Windows, it's much better use keyboard search when there are many apps. This is a good question, but apparently there is not a known solution yet to change this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Alfred](https://www.alfredapp.com/) in Mac, so work in windows was a really pain for me too without a similar tool.

I could not find a Windows default option solution, but I finally resolved with [Keypirinha](https://keypirinha.com) and his [TaskSwitcher Package](https://keypirinha.com/packages/taskswitcher.html?highlight=taskswitcher).

[CHECK this Link to see how it works in action](https://www.berrycast.com/conversations/728e68f6-1fa9-5d81-af85-2766e8bc2b87)

I hope you enjoy this solution.

Comment: This is indeed the closest thing that exists at the moment, it seems, to the Alfred workflow on Mac. One additional configuration I've got is to use `AutoHotkey` https://www.autohotkey.com/ to provide a single "Windows + Tab" hotkey (overriding the system default) for launching Keypiranha.